# Element does not float right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

The checkbox element inside the div does not float at the extreme right, as declared in CSS. The checkbox element float differs for every new div element. How do I get it right?

```css
div.container{
   height : 200px;
   width : 300px;
   box-shadow : 0 0 3px grey;
}
div.drop-down > div { width : 100px; background-color : #dddddd; }
div.drop-down > div input[type="checkbox"]{ float : right; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='drop-down'>
   <div>one<input type="checkbox"></div>
   <div>two<input type="checkbox"></div>
   <div>three<input type="checkbox"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set layout of parent element while using `float` on child elements.

There are many ways of setting layout of parent element. You can use `overflow: hidden` i.e:

```
div.drop-down > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `:after` pseudo element as well:

```
div.drop-down > div:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
div.container{
   height : 200px;
   width : 300px;
   box-shadow : 0 0 3px grey;
}
div.drop-down > div {
  width : 100px; background-color : #dddddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.drop-down > div input[type="checkbox"]{ float : right; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='drop-down'>
   <div>one<input type="checkbox"></div>
   <div>two<input type="checkbox"></div>
   <div>three<input type="checkbox"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```